udev triggered service not able to run sh script
I am working on a service to capture device-mapper dm-verity uevent. However, I am not able to figure out why the service is able to be triggered but fails to run my logger script.
I have the following rules (/etc/udev/rules.d/dm-verity.rules) based on this discussion (newline added for readability):
KERNEL=="dm-[0-9]*", \
ACTION=="change", \
SUBSYSTEM=="block", \
ENV{DM_VERITY_ERR_BLOCK_NR}!="", \
TAG+="systemd", \
ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="dm-verity.service"

I have the following service (/etc/systemd/system/dm-verity.service):
[Unit]
Description=dm-verity uevent logger

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dm-verity_log_error.sh

I have the following script (/usr/bin/dm-verity_log_error.sh):
#!/bin/bash

echo "dm-verity occurs" | my-logger-adaptor
exit 0

I can confirm from journal that the dm-verity.rules and dm-verity.service is triggered, however, it fails when it tries to execute dm-verity_log_error.sh. Journal log snippet as follows.
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: About to execute: /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/dm-verity_log_error.sh
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Forked /bin/bash as 19823
systemd[19823]: dm-verity.service: Kernel keyring not supported, ignoring.
systemd[19823]: dm-verity.service: Executing: /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/dm-verity_log_error.sh
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Changed dead -> start
systemd[1]: Starting dm-verity uevent logger
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: cgroup is empty
audit[19823]: ANOM_ABEND auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 pid=19823 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash.bash" sig=11 res=1
systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 19823 (bash).
systemd[1]: Child 19823 (bash) died (code=killed, status=11/SEGV)
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Child 19823 belongs to dm-verity.service.
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Changed start -> failed
systemd[1]: dm-verity.service: Job dm-verity.service/start finished, result=failed
systemd[1]: Failed to start dm-verity uevent logger

From the logs, it seem like there is an error when executing the bash shell to run the script (code=killed, status=11/SEGV) but I am not quite sure the cause of it. Any pointer to some documents or possible solutions on the problem?
My thoughts on what might be the cause:

Maybe it is because of systemd.exec executing the command in sandbox environment so that the bash shell does not has all of the necessary environment (reference 1
Maybe I invoke dm-verity_log_error.sh incorrectly in ExecStart= attribute field. Starting the service with systemctl start dm-verity.service is successful. I did some other test with ExecStart=/bin/ls and it can also run successfully when triggered by the rules.
Maybe dm-verity_log_error.sh did run, but ends too quickly. However, I am not sure if the main process in the journal is referring to the dm-verity.service that finished or referring to the ``dm-verity_log_error.sh` script itself.

I have tried to search for similar problem online but have not find one quite that match my problem. Maybe I am using the wrong keyword to search. I have read the following reference so far:

udev rules to trigger systemd service
how udev works
how to start service with udev event

I am using a development board running Yocto 2.6, and systemd 239.

Have you tried adding the full path to my-logger-adaptor in the shell script?

What happens if you systemctl start the service manually? The problem seems to be completely unrelated to udev, as your process is not run within the udev environment, nor even run by udev directly at all.

@Popup yes, unfortunately it also produce the same error when using with full path

@grawity when using systemctl start to manually start the service, the script can execute successfully. I agree that the issue seems to be unrelated with udev. I am thinking maybe it has to do with how the script or shell is invoked from the ExecStart= directive. I wonder if the service triggered by udev rules runs under different environment compared to the one run manually with systemctl start.

Are you using SELinux? (try getenforce to find out.)

@Popup SELinux/AppArmor is not enabled on the board. After some testing, it seems like after dm-verity occurs, the system is in a corrupted state where any new shell cannot be spawned. Hence any script or command that spawns for a new shell to execute will fail. With that said seems like issue is not udev/service related.
